# New objects not showing up

Tags: objects

I downloaded a model of a car online and I was able to colour and texture it without any problem. But in the modelling tab, I'm not able to select any of the individual parts of the car or add any new objects. For example, if I try to add a light, I can grab it, move it, but it just doesn't show up in the outliner or viewport. help!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13ADw3pDweaAi5ZPVZdCiqL7IV1mQ708u/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You need to reactivate the *Show Overlays* option:

[image]

Comment: Oh I totally overlooked that! thanks a ton mate!

Comment: And also select the Scene Collection if you want a new object to be created at the root of the Outliner